# What does this sequence "\\+?" do in a string?

Tags: java

Trying to comprehend someone else's codes. using `split()`

```
String e1 = "y=2x-5";
String[] t1 = e1.split("(y=)|(x\\+?)");
```

splits it to. `2`, `-5`.

I've googled around but couldn't find an explanation for these operators in a `String`.   Thanks for your help.  In additions to the resources listed.  here is an additional tutorial on Regular Expressions
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

Comment: Read the `Pattern` class javadoc.

Comment: `+` without the backslash has a special meaning in regexes, so `+` with the backslash just means to look for the `+` character.  The following `?` means the `+` character is optional.  So one of the delimiters it splits on is `x` possibly followed by `+`.

Comment: In a literal string `\\ ` simply turns into a single `\ ` character.  Which would be uninteresting were it not that the whole string is a "regular expression" string.

Comment: I don't understand, you apparently know what it does since you posted a link to a regex documentation?

Comment: `In additions to the resources listed` what resources listed?

Answer (score 1):

Split method in a String object requires a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In your code, the string (y=)|(x\+?) is a regular expression, then \+ means to look for the literal character '+' in the String e1, and ? means that the character '+' is optional (may appear or not in the String e1).

Answer (score 0):

`.split()` uses regular expressions as a parameter.

If you search for regex reference, it will explain what the operators mean, and how to use them.

Here is a good regex tester that gives contextual help on the operators as you type: http://regex101.com/

As to your regex, it breaks down like this:

```
"(y=)|(x\\+?)"
```

After escape processing, this breaks down to:

```
(y=)|(x\+?)
```

`()` tell regex this is a `match group`, it means we want something returned if it can be found.

`(y=)` says match any literal `y=` text found.

`(x\+?)` says match any literal `x` followed by a literal `+`. However the `?` is an operator, saying the previous character can appear zero or more times. It basically says, if there is an x, match it and any following `+` chars.

Since you are passing this to `split()`, the method uses these matches to break the string into components.

It is saying split the string at `y=` or `x[+[+[...]]]`.

In your case it splits at `y=` and `x`, which results in `2` and `-5`.

Comment: `?` in regex means it appears either zero times or one time.  It's an [optional quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), which can also be used to make expressions less greedy (`pop.*kernel` as opposed to `pop.*?kernel`).